# Issue on Foreign Key when deleting artist in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm making a program which adds/delete/modify artists/albums/tracks in a database, and when trying to delete an artist I get this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`chinook`.`album`, CONSTRAINT `FK_AlbumArtistId` FOREIGN KEY (`ArtistId`) REFERENCES `artist` (`ArtistId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:932)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5094)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
at modelo.dao.ArtistaDAO.eliminarArtista(ArtistaDAO.java:103)
at vista.VistaArtistasBuscar.actionPerformed(VistaArtistasBuscar.java:164)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I think I know what the problem is but I don't know how to solve it; I guess I have to apply a `on delete cascade` but I don't know how to do that; I must say that every modification to the DB has to be done trough the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have foreign keys, that are set without **ON DELETE CASCADE** option.

If you can edit DB Schema add it that way

```
FOREIGN KEY (foreign_key) 
REFERENCES table_2(foreign_key) 
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

This way when record where foreign_key (which is primary key in table_2) gets deleted all records referencing this key in table where you setup this option will get deleted too. To do this mutually you have to do this in both tables.

To put that in your perspective, propably you want to delete all artist songs when you delete him. So in table songs modify it like that:

```
FOREIGN KEY (artist_key) 
REFERENCES artists(artist_key) 
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: The issue is that I can't touch DB, this is for a project and every change I make to the DB it must be done trough the program itself